# How to override .htaccess with new rules without ftp or edit it manual

Tags: php, theme-options, htaccess

I want script will add new rules to current `.htaccess` and user no need to ftp or edit it manually.

Example, I use timthumb for resize image on my theme and want rewrite the URL and current `.htaccess` will be something like this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^images/thumb/(.*) timthumb.php?filename=$1
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Question

How to add the new rule to the `.htacces` on my theme option.

Enable Mod rewrite for Timthumb? : [Yes] [No]

If click [Yes] `RewriteRule ^images/thumb/(.*) timthumb.php?filename=$1` will automatic added to current `.htaccess`

Let me know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add extra rules right after the `^index\.php$` line via the `WP_Rewrite` class, more specifically the `add_external_rule()` method. They are added to the `non_rewrite_rules` array, [which is written in the `mod_rewrite_rules()` method](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.5/wp-includes/rewrite.php#L1702).

This is a very simple example. You should still flush the rewrite rules (once), either on plugin activation or by visiting the *Permalinks* page.

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse9966_init' );
function wpse9966_init()
{
    global $wp_rewrite;
    // The pattern is prefixed with '^'
    // The substitution is prefixed with the "home root", at least a '/'
    $wp_rewrite->add_external_rule( 'images/thumb/(.*)$', 'timthumb.php?filename=$1' );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it worked. I just flush the rules on activation theme.

Comment: `add_action('admin_init', 'wpse9966_init');` call on theme activation and I add `$wp_rewrite->flush_rules(true);` in the function and it work like a charm. If without `$wp_rewrite->flush_rules(true);` this won't work.

Comment: @wow: You should not call `flush_rules()` on every init, only when the rules change (when the user changes the setting). This is an "expensive" operation, it takes some time.